# Is there any way to get Chiselled Effect in chart js?

Tags: chart.js, bar-chart, chartjs-2.6.0, react-chartjs, chartjs-plugin-zoom

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbJyY.png)

is there any attribute or any way to get this effect on chartjs

Comment: If my answer has helped you, could you please select it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

The ChartJS plugin section can be found here:

https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=chartjs-chart-

The one you are after is probably this:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-plugin-style

Examples are here:

https://nagix.github.io/chartjs-plugin-style/